Exporting data from table using QGIS
I have a large Shapefile which contain several species (more than 300) from Gbif dataset, something like this:



ID
Specie
Season
Origins




1
Sp1
1
1


1
Sp1
2
2


1
Sp1
3
1


1
Sp2
1
2


1
Sp2
2
1


1
Sp2
3
1



So, what I need is to separate in single shape file for each specie, maintaining all data, for example:
Sp1.shp must have all the information:



ID
Specie
Season
Origins




1
Sp1
1
1


1
Sp1
2
2


1
Sp1
3
1



Sp2.shp must have all the information, like this:



ID
Specie
Season
Origins




1
Sp2
1
2


1
Sp2
2
1


1
Sp2
3
1



I know it can do selecting and exporting each species one by one. However, I think could done more efficient and faster.

Search your processing tool on split.  There's a split vector tool and a SAGA split by attribute tool.
